# Today I observed a referral through a site Biztool.corp.google.com

Tags: url, traffic, web-traffic

Today I observed a referral at my site from `biztool.corp.google.com` Which was redirected to moma webpage

Can Someone Please Explain If I should Block the Referral

Comment: What is a "moma webpage"?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - MOMA is the title of the google intranet